# Store a long variable in EEPROM

Tags: arduino, eeprom

My problem is the following:

I like to store data in an EEPROM like

```
char errorflag[] = "1234567"; 
i2c_eeprom_write_page(0x50, 0, (byte *)errorflag, sizeof(errorflag));
```

Perfect, no problems so far. But how can I save a long stored in a variable instead? Of course the following is not working, but it shows my what I like to do:

```
long long_variable = 1234567;
char errorflag[] = long_variable;  
i2c_eeprom_write_page(0x50, 0, (byte *)errorflag, sizeof(errorflag));
```

I tried quite a lot and it could not be to hard to figure it out but it seems I am to blind to see...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save the data as raw binary:

```
long long_variable = 1234567;
i2c_eeprom_write_page(0x50, 0, (byte *) long_variable, sizeof(long_variable));
```

If you want to convert the variable to text and save that (including `'\0'` terminator):

```
long long_variable = 1234567;
char errorflag[16];
sprintf(errorflag, "%ld", long_variable);
i2c_eeprom_write_page(0x50, 0, (byte *) errorflag, strlen(errorflag) + 1);
```

Comment: "sprintf(errorflag, "%ld", long_variable);" this made my day, thanks a lot!